# seaborn jointplot TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have problem with using python Seaborn library. This is my code:

```
#Importing main libraries
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import numpy as np

# For Visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
%matplotlib inline

url = 'https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/eureconometrics-assets/Dataset%20Files%20for%20On-Demand%20Course/Exercises%20and%20datasets/Module%201/TrainExer11.txt'

df2 = pd.read_csv(url,delim_whitespace=True)
df2.head()
df2.info()
#All columns types are int64
sns.jointplot('Age','Excenditures',data=df2,kind='scatter')
```

Output of my code is error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 sns.jointplot('Age','Excenditures',data=df,kind='scatter')
>
> C:\WinPython-32bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py in jointplot(x, y, data, kind, stat_func, color, size, ratio, space,
>   dropna, xlim, ylim, joint_kws, marginal_kws, annot_kws, **kwargs)
>       796     grid = JointGrid(x, y, data, dropna=dropna,
>       797                      size=size, ratio=ratio, space=space,
>   --> 798                      xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
>       799 
>       800     # Plot the data using the grid
>
> C:\WinPython-32bit-3.5.2.2\python-3.5.2\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py
>   in **init**(self, x, y, data, size, ratio, space, dropna, xlim, ylim) 
>   1659             not_na = pd.notnull(x) & pd.notnull(y)    1660
>   x = x[not_na]
>   -> 1661             y = y[not_na]    1662     1663         # Find the names of the variables
>
> TypeError: string indices must be integers

What's wrong with my code? Using other data works fine!

BR mls

Comment: It was mine typographical error in the name of the column Expenditures.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have a simple syntax problem in your code:

```
sns.jointplot('Age','Expenditures',data=df2,kind='scatter')
```

And it will work fine!

[image]